# Is there an R function for listing all possible combinations for column names

Tags: r

I Have a data frame of 3 column names. I need to list all 2 combinations of these column names.

```
   Col A    Col B   Col C
   44        27       43
   41        27       39
   29        39       28
   21        34       28
   19         2       26
```

I need to have below output

```
  df
  COl A & COl B
  COl A & COl C
  COl B & COl C
```

Comment: you could do `combn(names(df), 2, paste,collapse = " & ")`

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as Ronaks answer but returns a data frame, which is think your question implies:

```
library(tidyverse)

combn(names(df), 2) %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  transmute(all_combos = paste(V1, " & ", V2))
```

which returns

```
     all_combos
1 ColA  &  ColB
2 ColA  &  ColC
3 ColB  &  ColC
```